# How to use Sphinx autofunction for file outside module

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I have a package written, call it MAUDIE. Also in the folder containing the MAUDIE modules, I have a `docs` folder containing the sphinx documentation, and a `tutorial` folder. In the `tutorial` folder, I have a file `use_Maudie.py`, it's a script to run a basic use case at the command line, with a function `use_maudie()`.

I want to include the docustring from `use_maudie()` in my documentation, and tried the following:

```
.. currentmodule:: MAUDIE.tutorial.use_Maudie
.. autofunction:: use_maudie
```

This (probably obviously) didn't work, as there is no module MAUDIE.tutorial.
Is there a way to include the formatted version of the `use_maudie()` Docustring and still leave `use_Maudie.py` in the `tutorial` folder?

Comment: If the `tutorial` folder is in `sys.path`, then `.. currentmodule:: use_Maudie` followed by `.. autofunction:: use_maudie` should work.

Comment: @mzjn, The sys.path directs to the `MAUDIE` folder, which *contains* the tutorial folder. So it's `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/Users/me/Desktop/'))`, which is where the `MAUDIE` folder is, and then the path to `tutorial` is  /Users/me/Desktop/MAUDIE/tutorial/

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need one `sys.path` entry for `/Users/me/Desktop/MAUDIE` and one for `/Users/me/Desktop/MAUDIE/tutorial`.

Comment: @mzjn Ah Ha!! Thank you :)